# Как расшифровать два HTML заXORеных одним ключем?

Tags: криптография

В общем, такая проблема. Есть какие то 2 html страницы(136 275 бит и 357 992 бит). Их зашифровали XORом, использовали ключ, который полностью покрывает оба файла(370 093 бит если не ошибаюсь). По идее, если бы их закодировали разными ключами, это было бы нерасшифруемо, но ключ 1 на 2 файла. Задание- используя 2 файла, полученные в результате шифрования, найти исходные html страницы. 
вопрос- как это вообще сделать?

Comment: ну второй файл целиком вы точно не получите. А так выполняете xor двух файлов получаете xor двух открытых текстов между собой. зная их и зная допустимые в html символы для начала грубо оцениваем и отбрасываем значения каждого байта ключа, который дал бы в любом из файлов недопустимые символы. потом начинаем атаку по словарям распространенных в html слов (т.е. тегов и их атрибутов) подбираем такие значения ключа, что бы осмысленный текст в первом файле давал осмысленный текст во втором. Вот что то мне подсказывает, что первый байт в обоих файлах сейчас одинаков, потому что он `<`

Comment: шифровали XORом- т.е. просто побитовое сложение html файла и ключа

Comment: Если длина ключа действительно равна целому файлу - то никак вы не расшифруете.